# Suggestions for popping complex navigation path to root (path includes multiple nested UINavigationControllers and modal overlays)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm working on an application that includes relatively complex navigation paths through a storyboard of views.  The scenario is, I have a UINavigationController with a number of controllers, each of which can potentially present modals that themselves have UINavigationCollers which have their own sets of controllers that can present modals, etc. etc. etc.  My problem is that I need a general way to essentially cancel out and pop all the way back up to the root view controller.

Would you suggest a mechanical approach that backtracks view controllers via a mix of  popToRootViewControllerAnimated and dismissViewControllerAnimated calls?  Or is there an easier way to jump back to my root given this complex path?

This feels like it would be a common problem.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Note, I've seen related questions - I already know how to perform the necessary steps to pop the controllers when the path is known.  What I'm looking for is a way to do this in a general way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem by manipulating the UIWindow.rootViewController property.  This allows me to quickly pop back to the root from an arbitrary view controller.  From the docs: "If the window has an existing view hierarchy, the old views are removed before the new ones are installed."  Thanks to the folks who responded.

```
- (void)popToRootViewControllerFromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController
{
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *rootView = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RootViewController"];

    [fromViewController presentViewController:rootView animated:NO completion:^{
        self.window.rootViewController = rootView;
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just call popToRootViewacontroller on your your main navigation controller child that should be all you need.

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me.  If I'm in another navigation controller that was presented as a modal from a view in my main navigation controller popping the main controller didn't do anything, which is I think what I would expect.  I ended up solving this by manipulating the UIWindow's rootViewController property.  Thanks for the response!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help :( Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class which implements UINavigationControllerDelegate and have all the UINavigationControllers set a single instance of that class as a delegate. Then, if you know the view controller you want to pop to, you can use

```
– (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)nc
      willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)vc
                    animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

If you're not at the desired view controller yet, keep popping.

Comment: This sounds kind of like what popToRootViewController gets you for free.  I don't see how this helps me with the case in which I'm a few modals deep and a few pages deep into a navigation controller - how do I know when I need to call dismissViewControllerAnimated vs. popToRootViewController?  I ended up solving this via the UIWindow's rootViewController property - see below.  Thanks!